# If command in selenium IDE

Tags: browser-automation, selenium-ide

By using Selenium ID extension for fireofx (or chrome), I have problems by using "if" command and the !statusOK variable.

[image]

In particular I get this error:

```
verifyElementPresent on id=login-title OK
15:56:28
echo: ${!statusOK}
15:56:29
5.
if on ${!statusOK} Failed:
15:56:29
Unexpected token {
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

seems to be a Firefox issue, in this kind there is same issue in another post:

Browser Version:
Check your browser version and when it is the latest one then downgrade the browser version. The reason is, that selenium IDE has ended the support with firefox browser.
As one user said "From Version 55 selenium IDE will not support firefox".

Please check the link within: [Selenium IDE type not saving text](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34348/selenium-ide-type-not-saving-text)

Seems that this describes your issue...Try to use the workaround as described there.

Same as in github described: [Selenium IDE is not compatible with Firefox 55](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4406)

Comment: For me this happens also for chrome browser... I think that selenium ide is not still supported. What a pity, for easy text case, ide is more intuitive than web driver